# .po and .mo files UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, discord.py, gettext, po, mo

I have a Bot which im trying to make multilingual. Now when i try to run the command for the bot i get
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

I tried removing the  Emoji in the .po file and convert it back to .mo and then it worked. so it seems that  is the problem of that all.

Example: My german .po file:

```
msgid "PING_TITLE"
msgstr "**PING **"

msgid "PING_DESCRIPTION"
msgstr "Meine Latenz ist **{ping}ms**!"
```

my Command:

```py
import gettext
import io
import json
from datetime import datetime

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

        with open("data/languages.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            guild_languages = json.load(f)

        lang = guild_languages.get(str(interaction.guild.id), "en")
        trans = gettext.translation(
            domain="ping", localedir="locales", languages=[lang], fallback=True
        )

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=str(trans.gettext("PING_TITLE")),
            description=str(trans.gettext("PING_DESCRIPTION").format(ping=ping)),
            color=0x1365EA,
            timestamp=datetime.now(),
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f"{interaction.user}", icon_url=f"{interaction.user.avatar.url}"
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Ping(client))
```

Like i said, without the Emoji everything works fine! But i want the Emoji to be part of the Command.

Reminder: I also have a .mo file.

Comment: I don't think the emoji is the real issue here, you would most likely get the same error with any non-ASCII character, for example `ä` or `é`.

Comment: But is there a way to fix it? @LauriNurmi